# How to send response as JSON in Jersey Rest

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have Jersey Rest Webservice with server side code as

```
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Employee> getEmployees()
    {
        return new EmployeeService().getEmployees();
    }
```

T
I am testing the service from chrome rest client.
 This works fine with 
    Accept: application/xml 
** But when I am requesting this with code 
     Accept: application/json

I am getting the following exception:-

javax.servlet.ServletException:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.rshekhar.domain.Employee, genericType=class com.rshekhar.domain.Employee.
```

What is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details related to jersey setup (entity classes annotations for starters)

Do you use JAXB? Which version of Jersey?

Here is nice starting point for your goal: https://github.com/jasonray/jersey-starterkit/wiki/Serializing-a-POJO-to-xml-or-json-using-JAXB

Comment: I found this nice article related to this & it works!! http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jersey's built-in Jackson JSON library to automatically serialize JSON from any POJO classes. You just need to add Jackson JSON library to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also in order to activate the POJO mapping of Jersey, you need to add the following lines in web.xml:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Then if your class method `EmployeeService().getEmployees()` returns a list of employees, Jersey will serialize it to something like (JSON array)

```
{"employees": ["name":"Adam", "name":"Robert", ....]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here and try out the example. It almost exactly the same usecase you have mentioned.

[multiple content types in jax-rs](http://www.jasonwhaley.com/blog/2011/01/18/multiple-content-types-in-jax-rs/)

Answer (score 0):

With latest version like 1.19.1 jersey.

add following dependency

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.10.0.pr1'
```

in gradle

or if you are using maven.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
</dependency>
```

in maven
It will work.

Thanks,
Praveen R.