# Jersey Exception when trying to convert a custom object to json

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

Before you guys mark this question a duplicate, I would like to tell you guys that I have already tried the solutions from

[A message body writer for Java class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108161/a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-not-found)

[javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: JSON support in Java REST Webservices with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367158/javax-ws-rs-webapplicationexception-com-sun-jersey-api-messageexception-json-s)

https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson

And I am still stuck. Here is the exception that I am having.

```
24-Apr-2016 02:03:00.655 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write A message body writer for Java class com.upwork.magnus.model.FirstException, and Java type class com.upwork.magnus.model.FirstException, and MIME media type application/json was not found
24-Apr-2016 02:03:00.656 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

24-Apr-2016 02:03:00.656 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.logException Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.upwork.magnus.model.FirstException, and Java type class com.upwork.magnus.model.FirstException, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.upwork.magnus.model.FirstException, and Java type class com.upwork.magnus.model.FirstException, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    ... 29 more
```

Here is `pom.xml` file dependencies file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is the line where i am trying to return the object

```
    public Response response() throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (fe != null){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity(fe)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The `fe` object is of type `FirstException`. And here is that class

```
public class FirstException implements Serializable{
    private int errorCode;
    private String message;

    public FirstException(int errorCode, String message) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() { return errorCode;}
}
```

and here is my ***web.xml*** part to configure pojo

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.upwork.magnus.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**I Tried removing everything but `jersey-json` from my `pom.xml` file as suggested by few but still the same issue. Here is that `pom.xml`**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why FlightException isn't an Exception subclass?

Comment: Sorry, that's just the name that i am using. Most probably it will be changed to `ErrorResponse`.

Comment: First thing you should do is get rid of _everything_ jackson you have in your pom file. `jersey-json` pulls in the Jackson you need. You have all these different version of different stuff for no reason.

Comment: Removed and tried. Same issue. I am going to post updated pom.xml in my question. Thanks

Comment: You can add `@XmlRootElement` to the `FirstException` class. It should work. But it's really an undesirable work-around to the underlying problem, which is "why isn't jackson being used". Looking at the error, if you look at the list of providers, you don't see Jackson. I am not sure why.

Comment: You can try to add this package `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` to packages `init-param`. Just separate them with a comma. Remove the `@XmlRootElement` (if you added it). Then run it again. See what happens

Comment: I actually stumbled upon a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161466/how-do-i-use-the-jersey-json-pojo-support) where someone suggested the same. However, I didn't know if i can use `,` to supply multiple argument to `param-value`. I did so and it worked :) 

Could you please post this as a comment so that I can select this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error, you will see that the Jackson json provider is not one the providers registered. Only the default Jersey ones are, which make use of JAXB functionality. So you could annotate the `FirstException` class with `@XmlRootElement`, and it should work. But this is really an undesirable work-around the to underlying problem, which is "why isn't Jackson being used?".

What you can do make sure Jackson is being used is to add the `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` package to the list of packages to scan. This package contains the Jackson json provider.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.upwork.magnus.api,
        org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```